# Referencing section title and enumerate item number

Tags: cross-referencing

I have multiple sections with enumerations in them. Given a reference, is it possible to get the section name it belongs to? And also the item number as well.

For example, given this code (with fictionary commands `itemref` and `secref`)

```
\section*{Example title}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item first one
    \item second one \label{ref:anchor}
\end{enumerate}

\section*{Second title}
See item \itemref{ref:anchor} in section \secref{ref:anchor}.
```

the result would be

> Example title
>   1. first one
>   2. second one
>
> Second title
>   See item 2 in section "Example title".

I've found numerous ways to reference a section name, but as I understand it, the anchor must be the section itself, which wouldn't work in my case since I move items around in this document and I'd like it to be dynamic.

EDIT: I have a working solution with the `enumitem` package for the item number reference, so only the section name is missing.

Comment: With `\section*`, you're not going to have a section number.

Comment: @TH. That's intentional, since my section titles contain only numbers and it would be confusing. Hence my need to reference section with titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `zref` package can help you out here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[titleref,user]{zref}
\ztitlerefsetup{}

\newcommand*\itemlabel[1]{%
        \label{#1}%
        \zlabel{#1}%
}
\newcommand*\itemref[1]{\ref{#1}}
\newcommand*\secref[1]{``\ztitleref{#1}''}

\begin{document}

\section*{Example title}
\begin{enumerate}
\item first one
\item second one\itemlabel{ref:anchor}
\end{enumerate}

\section*{Second title}
See item~\itemref{ref:anchor} in Section \secref{ref:anchor}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The one real difference to what you posted is I defined an `\itemlabel` macro which you need to use in place of `\label`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the `zref` packages seems really powerful. Your solution is perfect!